# LinkedIN javascript sdk is working on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Console is not displaying any error and browser displays an empty page even if I am not logged in to LinkedIN. If I keep any alert inside script, it is not popping up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: mykey
        authorize: true 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="IN/Login"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure your production domain is added to the 'Valid SDK Domains' list? - reference https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#

Comment: Yeah @matov I have added the server under Valid SDK Domains. However, the console should show if the domain is not added.